# mod_rewrite to add a php parameter to base url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm sure this question has been answered before but I'm not sure how to search for the answer because a google search is swamped with generic mod_rewrite url styling questions.

I have an .htaccess file with the following standard rule for redirecting a non-www query to a www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]
```

The site is structured as a single page application with two main pages and the site displays html based on the url parameters. Let's say page one is apples and page two is pears. I want to make it so if the user searches for website.com then the first rule will be invoked and it'll redirect to www.website.com. Then I want it to add a parameter so it becomes www.website.com/?p=apples since neither ?p=apples or ?p=pears was contained in the original search.

I tried several solutions but all of them seem to lead to redirect loops. This one unexpectedly leads to a redirect loop for example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^.*\?p=apples.*$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^.*\?p=pears.*$
RewriteRule .* http://www.website.com/?p=apples [R] # also how can this be generalized so it's not domain name specific
```

Comment: Have you cleared your cache after you have add that to the .htaccess? do you have .htaccess in any other directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for. If you are trying to combine it so that it redirects to www and also if the query string is empty then redirect to `?p=apples`, then this code should work for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !p=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/?p=apples [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```